# How can I concatenate arithmetic and strings?

Tags: javascript, types, concatenation

So javascript uses the plus operator to concatenate strings with strings and/or integers like so:
`<script>document.write("One plus Two equals " + 3);</script>`
`<script>document.write("One plus Two equals " + "three");</script>`

At least I think it does :/ --Because of this, things get confusing if I wanted to concatenate integers and/or strings with arithmetic. I shall try here anyway. don't laugh :(
`<script>document.write("One plus Two equals " + 1+2);</script>`?

I wonder, could the solution as easy as adding moar parentheses?!
`<script>document.write("One plus Two equals " + (1+2));</script>`

Am I way off base here?

Comment: Did you try these? Just try them and you will answer your own question!

Comment: Yes, that's the way you do it. Was that your question?

Comment: brso05 - I'm just reading for now.

Comment: Teemu - That was my question. Thanks breh!

Comment: @Musixauce3000 don't just read try things!